# Rabbitmq Connections tab showing as empty for Virtual host

Tags: rabbitmq, connection, virtualhost

In Rabbitmq Connections and Channels are showing as empty for different virtual hosts.

When Virtualhost =All,/  --> then connections and channels tab loading.

When user created Virtualhost ---> Connections and channels are showing as empty

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ and Erlang?

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.8.9
Erlang 23.1.2

Comment: That version of RabbitMQ is out of support. If you can reproduce this issue with a supported version of RabbitMQ, open an issue here - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues